# cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'Date' in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date

I was trying to compare the EndDate I received from the response to the current date but the EndDate from the response is string. Should I convert the request.EndDate to moment ?. What is the best way to address this issue ?

```
const today = new Date()

    if(this.request.EndDate > today){

    }
```

Comment: you should indeed cast your string to date, was it with moment or vanilla js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Date directly:

```js
const today = new Date();
const endDate = new Date('2020-04-23'); // replace with this.request.EndDate

if (endDate > today) {
    document.querySelector('#date').innerHTML = 'is greater than';
}
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```